# How do I create a super class list with son objects inside?

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to code a list which can include different classes that all extend from the same one.
I'm not using arraylist, im creating the lists myself, using the following basic structure:

```
public class L_Subjects {

    private Subject first;

    public L_Subjects(){
        this.first=null;
    }

    //methods (add, delete, length, etc.)

}

public class Subject{

    //variables of the subject
    private subject next;

    public Subject(/*variables*/){
        //setting the parameters to each variable
        this.next=null;
    }

    //methods

}
```

So each subject is "chained" to the next subject in the list by a "pointer" to it. The methods go through the list using loops using a subject object as an index (index=index.getnext();).

But now i want to add different types of subjects, using heritage, but without having a list for each type of subject. I still want a single list with all the subject that includes different objects of different classes that all extend subject. Is there any way i can do this without heavily modifying the base structure i use? maybe having next as a void?

Comment: You need to separate out the contents of the list from the structure of the list.

Comment: @CKing what do you mean by separating?